# How can I find element on mongo using $all operator with Yesod?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod, persistent

**Problem:**

I have a Person model to retrieve from [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb):

```
Person
    name Text
    favoriteFoods [Text]
```

This is my function:

```
getPersonsByFoods :: [Text] -> DB [Entity Person]
getPersonsByFoods foods = selectList [PersonFavoriteFoods ??? foods] []
```

I took a look at [Query filter combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.10.0/docs/Database-Persist.html#g:3) but I didn't find any function that can help me to deal with a list. I need I kind of `containsAll` function.

This is should be the final mongo query:

```
PersonModel.find({ favouriteFoods: { "$all" : ["sushi", "burger"]} });
```

**Meta:**

```
- yesod >=1.6 && <1.7
- yesod-core >=1.6 && <1.7
- yesod-static >=1.6 && <1.7
- persistent >=2.9 && <2.10
- persistent-mongoDB >=2.8 && <2.9
- mongoDB
- persistent-template >=2.5 && <2.9
```

**Question:**

How can I achieve this result using Yesod?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [<-.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.10.0/docs/src/Database.Persist.html#%3C-.)

```
getPersonsByFoods :: [Text] -> DB [Entity Person]
getPersonsByFoods foods = selectList [PersonFavoriteFoods <-. foods] []
```

Alternatively if you are also using [esqueleto](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-3.0.0/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html) you can:

```
getPersonsByFoods :: [Text] -> DB [Entity Person]
getPersonsByFoods foods = selectList [PersonFavoriteFoods `in_` valList foods] []
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, (<-.) doesn't work in my case because it checks if the value is in a given list. In my case value is a list. Can be something like ["banana", "sushi", "burger"] and should be found.